# How to short url address with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My code produce URL like this:

```
http://domain.com/netRacuni/tcpdf/examples/pdf.php?key=bi5u3w2zys1v9sqijomsqyya5ge2v5
```

How I can make it like this:

```
http://agroagro.com/bi5u3w2zys1v9sqijomsqyya5ge2v5
```

so only domain.com+key to be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can a try a rule like this in your root .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^netRacuni/tcpdf/examples/pdf.php$ /%1? [L]
```

**Edit:** Sounds like you want it the other way around. Your question isn't too clear.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /netRacuni/tcpdf/examples/pdf.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Comment: hm I have now http://domain.com/netRacuni/tcpdf/examples/pdf.php?kljuc=wwbw91jsc1qdc92bq4b855ssg115wi and I try: http://domain.com/wwbw91jsc1qdc92bq4b855ssg115wi but give me 404 Not Found...

Comment: So you want it the other way around? Try the updated rule and see if that's what you want, if not add your current .htaccess rules to your question.